# Subspace topology and discrete space

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with usual topology and $A$ not enumerable such that $\tau_{A}$ the subspace topology in $A$ it is a discrete space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does an uncountable discrete subspace of the reals exist?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86357/does-an-uncountable-discrete-subspace-of-the-reals-exist)

Answer (score 4):

No. Note that $A$ is second countable and metrizable. Then $A$ must be separable. This is a contradiction with $A$ is discrete and uncountable!

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $\Bbb R^2$ has a countable base $\mathscr{B}$. If $\langle A,\tau_A\rangle$ is a discrete space, then for each $x\in A$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $B_x\cap A=\{x\}$. The map $A\to\mathscr{B}:x\mapsto B_x$ is injective (one-to-one), so ... ?

Comment: @Brain: Your answer is also nice; +1)

Answer (score 3):

No. If it were so then we could create a collection of open subsets of the plane, one for each point of the space, all of which are disjoint. But each open subset would contain at least one point with rational coordinates which is not in any other such open subset. Thus, the cardinality must be less than or equal to that of the rationale, making it enumerable.

Comment: This is fairly seriously incomplete. Relative discreteness of $A$ directly tells you only that there are open sets $V_x$ for $x\in A$ such that $V_x\cap A=\{x\}$ for each $x\in A$; it takes moderately significant work to show that they can be chosen to be pairwise disjoint. In particular, it’s entirely possible to have a separable Tikhonov space with an uncountable discrete subset — even an uncountable **closed** discrete subset.

Comment: But in a metric space, can't you just take a ball with radius the minimum distance to the nearest point, then halve it (for each point)?

Comment: Yes, you can, but I think that it’s a significant enough step to require some explicit acknowledgement, if only in the form of a *Why?* appended to the statement.

Comment: Hi, what about my answer?

Comment: This is the second time today that my intuition about discrete sets has been screwy... thanks for the example!

Comment: @Paul: The new version looks fine; +1.