# Is the closure of a discrete subspace of $[0,1]$ necessarily countable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Question is in the title.

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86357/does-an-uncountable-discrete-subspace-of-the-reals-exist), every discrete subspace of $[0,1]$ must be countable.  But what about its closure?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919450/is-the-closure-of-a-countable-g-delta-set-countable).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the middle-thirds [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), and take the midpoint of every interval that is *removed* during its construction.

These midpoints evidently form a discrete set.

However, every point in the Cantor set is the limit of a sequence of midpoints, and the Cantor set is uncountable.

Comment: In fact, every closed nowhere dense subset of $[0,1]$ is the closure of a discrete set.